# java.net.URL retrieves unintelligible stream

Tags: java, url

I have been using a java code to retrieve an url content. The code does not work for https://www.amazon.es/. A similar python code does achieve retrieving an amazon url content.

The java code:

```
URL url = new URL(urlToScan);
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(url.openStream(), StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
for (String temp = reader.readLine(); temp != null; temp = reader.readLine())
    builder.append(temp);
webpage = builder.toString();
```

The python code:

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
url = "https://www.amazon.es/"
page = urlopen(url)
html_bytes = page.read()
html = html_bytes.decode("utf-8")
print(html)
```

I searched amazon's html on my own looking for the used charset (in case it was a charset issue) and they are using `charset="utf-8"`.
As the html is 22,000+ lines long, I thought it could be some parsing error for long Strings. I also tried with a `ByteArrayOutputStream` and then instancing using `String(byte[], charset)` constructor.
Java output:

```
?
```

Why is not java.net.URL retrieving properly the url content?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe it's because of `User-Agent`. To set `User-Agent`, using `URLConnection`:

```
URL url = new URL("https://www.amazon.es/");
URLConnection connection = url.openConnection();
connection.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64)");

BufferedInputStream bufferedInputStream = new BufferedInputStream(connection.getInputStream());
BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(bufferedInputStream));

StringBuilder buffer = new StringBuilder();
String inputLine;
while ((inputLine = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
    buffer.append(inputLine).append("\n");
}
bufferedReader.close();

System.out.println(buffer.toString());
```

While Python's `urllib` should be using certain `User-Agent` by default.

Comment: Worked perfectly fine. Thank you!